# Upload to multiple servers simultaneously with Sublime SFTP Plugin?

Tags: sublimetext2, sftp, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using the SFTP Plugin in Sublime to manage uploading files automatically to my web servers. I've found that it is possible to create different configurations and manually switch between them, but I would like to be able to have multiple servers included in one configuration file so I can upload to two servers at once (the servers contain identical files and are set up under a load balancer so for testing purposes I need to keep both servers in sync). Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks!